# While using CCL when I connect to cast device from LocalPlayerActivity the VideoCastControllerActivity does not open

Tags: android, chromecast

I have already declared the **VideoCastControllerActivity** in the manifest but the main problem is that:

1. I open LocalPlayerActivity
2. I play my video in videoview
3. Then I connect to cast device
4. connection is established
5. But in this case VideoCastControllerActivity does not open up.

It goes inside onApplicationConnected block as well but it nothing happens.

But if I first connect to the cast device in the activity that is step ahead of this LocalPlayerActivity and then I come to localPlayerActivity and if I play it shows up the VideoCastControllerActivity and everything works fine in this case.

Comment: Why don't you debug your issue? What I am seeing here is that something is not working the way you want, so instead of immediately posting a question here, how about doing some debugging yourself, trying to understand the flow of your program and see why it is not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response again. Yes obviously I am trying to debug via logcat and enabling the logUtils too. But as this is my first try in chromecast I am having lot of problems. Your every comment has helped me a lot and I expect same.